# Laravel ORM relationship, authorization user

Tags: laravel, eloquent, phpmyadmin, relationship, policy

I want to authorize users with the 'seller' role. How to provide a policy to 'sellers' so that sellers cannot read order data from other sellers.

My orders table has relations with 4 table. [Here's my orders Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40g52.png)

**Order model [Order.php]**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'order_items','order_id','product_id')->withPivot('quantity','price');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**Order policies [OrderPolicy.php]**

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Order;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class OrderPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function before($user, $ability)
    {
        if ($user->hasRole('admin')) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function browse(User $user)
    {
        return $user->hasRole('seller');
    }


    public function read(User $user, Order $order)
    {
        if(empty($order-> )) {
            return false;
        }

        return $user->id == $order-> ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think as long as the order item belongs to the user, no matter what role the user has, they can still see their order

Comment: someone correct me if i am wrong, but i think that is not possible on models and classes. to achieve that policy you must provide the data validation on the controller.